What is the symbol on the face opposite ● (solid black circle)?
MAIN QUESTION:
Three different views of the same cube are shown.  What is the symbol on the face opposite ● (solid black circle)?


BONUS QUESTION:
Would the answer to the Main Question be unique if you were only shown View 1 and View 3 of the cube?

Attribution:  Mostly Gauss Contest Grade 7, 2020; partly me.

Here is an answer that works without rotating the cubes in your mind:

 Since the black dot is not visible in views 1 and 2, the symbol on the opposite face to the black dot has to be visible in both views 1 and 2. The only symbol appearing in both of these views is the crossed square.


+1 What an amazing observation!

The symbol opposite of • is:

 ☒

Because:

 view 3 must be view 1 rotated in the horizontal plane, and view 2 rules out that the bottom side of view 1 is also a □ as it introduces the ■, which must be the bottom

Bonus question:

 No, without view 2, there is a possibility that the bottom is also a □, which then is ambiguous if the + or ☒ is opposite.


Your insight for the bonus is correct,  but if there's a second square, it could go at any of the faces not in view 1, not just the bottom.
